# Problem creating route with array_filter PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am creating a PDP API where the routes are created from an array:

```
arrayRotas = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(count(array_filter($arrayRotas)) == 0) {

    // Quando alguém simplesmente acessa a url raiz da API
    $json = array (
        "info"=>"Seja bem vindo(a) à nossa api",
        "Descrição"=>"Esta url é somente para a equipe de desenvolvimento."
    );
    
    echo json_encode($json, true);

    return;

} else {

    // Passando somente um índice no array $arrayRotas
    if(count(array_filter($arrayRotas)) == 1){

        // Quando se faz nenhuma requisição à API em /register
        if(array_filter($arrayRotas)[1] == "register") {
```

But, when I try this, it shows nothing:

```
if(array_filter($arrayRotas)[1] == "info" && array_filter($arrayRotas)[2] == 2){
                //echo "hi"; 
                print_r($arrayRotas);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `arrayRotas` doesn't have a `$`  on the first line?

Comment: Read [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: When I copy and paste I could get a $ but there is an original code